# Flag Update in james james-2.3.2.1

Tags: apache, james

I am new to `Apache` james,  using james-2.3.2.1, I am able to send and retrieve the mail but unaware about how to update the flag of the the retrived message . I tried with pop3 but is not allowing me for  the same.

Having error :

> javax.mail.IllegalWriteException: POP3 messages are read-only

Can you please suggest me the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the OS is a Linux based and seems that you don't have the right access there.